# Unable to add property to object using method with this keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a property to an object using a method. Here is the code:

```js
const siddhu = {
    name: 'Siddhu',
    friends: ['Dylan', 'Jordans', 'Aathi'],
    setBestFriend: () => this.bestFriend = this.friends[0],
    setNumOfFriends: () => this.numOfFriends = this.friends.length,
}
siddhu.setBestFriend()
siddhu.setNumOfFriends()

console.log(`${siddhu.name} has ${siddhu.numOfFriends} friends, and his best friend is ${siddhu.bestFriend}`);
```

For some reason, this doesn't work. I know that changing the `this` keyword to `siddhu` fixes the problem, but this isn't ideal, as I want to be able to copy-paste this code multiple times, and I would have to change `siddhu` every time I did.

Comment: Also see [MDN Creating new objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#creating_new_objects) which shows how to create a custom object which you can reuse multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem - apparently you can't use `this` with arrow functions because then `this` would reference the arrow function. All credit goes to [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) for telling me!